# Github public page not working - Error 404

Tags: git, github

Hello all thanks for your help in advance!

I have made an index.html and a style.css under css folder on: https://github.com/hokkichan/coursera-test/tree/master/week2. The files were uploaded to github through git push.

In the repository settings, it has been chosen that "Source Your GitHub Pages site is currently being built from the master branch." Caymen theme was also chosen. After saving the settings, the page also displayed "Your site is ready to be published at https://hokkichan.github.io/coursera-test/."

However, I could not preview the site on github.io, on https://hokkichan.github.io/coursera-test/week2.html.  An error 404 occured.

May I know what should I do so that I can view the index.html on github.io?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Might be related to the issues GitHub is currently facing: https://www.githubstatus.com/

Comment: Here your site url is https://hokkichan.github.io/  but there is not such directory coursera-test in your repo. put your week 2 folder insider coursera-test folder.